# No retorna resultado de un select en una vista

Tags: python, jquery, django

Estoy aprendiendo a usar selects anidados, y usando esto en uno de mis proyectos, me da el siguiente error.
Estoy registrando un usuario en mi base de datos.
Mi usuario tiene un campo Provincia y otro municipio, donde uso mis select anidados. Estoy usando la librería select2 para llevar a cabo esto.
Funciona todo perfecto, pero cuando presiono el submit de mi form, y este envia mis datos. A mi vista no llega el contenido de mi select anidado. Me llega vacio y no tengo idea del porque

Este es el form que recibo en mi vista (Select Vacio):

```
<tr><th><label for="id_municipio">Municipio:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>Escoja una opción válida. Esa opción no está entre las disponibles.</li></ul> 
<select name="municipio" class="form-control" required id="id_municipio">   
<option value="">---------</option> 
</select></td></tr>
```

Este es el codigo que estoy usando para capturar mis datos en el select  municipio de forma dinamica de acuerdo a la provincia que seleccione el usuario:

```
$("Select[name='municipio']").select2({
    language:'es',
    ajax: {

              url: window.location.pathname,
              type: "POST",
              data: function (params) {
                          var queryParameters = {
                          term: params.term,
                          'id':id,
                          'action':'autocomplete',
                          }

                          return queryParameters;
              },

              processResults: function (data) {
                  return {results: data};
              },
          
              
          },
    
    placeholder: 'Municipio',
    minimumInputLength: 2,

})
```

Envio los datos del form a mi vista usando ajax con la siguiente funcion:

```
$("form").on("submit",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
      var parametros = new FormData(this) 
          parametros.append('action','registrar')
          
          $.ajax({
                    url:url,
                    type:"POST",
                    data:parametros,
                    dataType:'json',
                    processData: false,  
                    contentType: false  


                    }).done(function(data) {

                       if(!data.hasOwnProperty('error')){
                        callback();
                        return false;
                       }
                       else{
                        MensajeError(data.error);
                        
                        
                       }
                    })
})
```

form

```
<form>
          {% csrf_token %}


       <div class="row my-4 justify-content-center">
 
          <div class="col-md-3 ml-3">{{form.provincia}} </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 ml-3">{{form.municipio}} </div>
            
       </div>
        

      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-8">
            <div class="icheck-primary">
              <a href="{% url 'Login:login'%}">Ya tengo una cuenta (Iniciar Sesion)</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block">Register</button>
          </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Si pasas mas codigo miro de hecharte una mano. Me falta el form y button para poder te ayudar.
Basicamente tu this no es correcto.  De la forma que lo estas haciendo no se puede pasar el llamador.
Hay que capturar los parametros uno a uno para añadirlos al FormData

Comment: Ya actualize el problema, dime si necesitas algo mas.. Lo unico que no creo que este mal la forma de pasar el llamador, porque todos mis otros elementos llegan a la vista. El unico que llega vacio es mi select, Municipio.

Answer (score 0):

Yaaaaaa! lo resolvi.
No se si sea la manera mas optima de hacerlo. Pero funciona.
El problema estaba, cuando declaraba en mi clase form el campo (municipio) como none, con el objetivo de luego llenarlo usando ajax.

```
municipio = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Municipio.objects.none())
```

Lo que hice fue cambiar el none() por all() y luego con ajax, decido cuales municipios se muestran y cuales no, en dependencia de la provincia.

```
municipio = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Municipio.objects.all())
```

No creo que sea lo mas optimo porque estoy obligado a cargar todos los municipios en mi select. Pero funciona y es la unica manera que conozco hasta ahora. Si alguien conoce otra que me cuente. Gracias